# string literal converted to type or namespace for generics c#

Tags: c#, .net

I new to c# and I am trying to create a method which takes a string and then it instantiates an object using the string as a type.

```
public void CreateRepository( string name) { 
      var repository = new Repository<name>();
}
```

e.g.

Obviously I get a compiler error but how do I convert my string to a namespace?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? Why do you need to create the type from string and what do you want to do with the result later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
public void CreateRepository(string name)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(name);
    var genericRepositoryType = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    var repositoryObj = Activator.CreateInstance(genericRepositoryType );
    // N.B. repositoryObj variable is System.Object
    //      but is also an istance of Repository<name>
}
```